# What do I do with the stuff I pick up?

Tags: donkey-kong-94

I am playing the Game Boy version of *Donkey Kong* (downloaded from the 3DS eShop). I noticed that I can pick up some things (like a hat, in the 75m area of the first level). Unlike the hammer, it doesn't seem to have any immediate use.

What are items like this good for? If they are useful, how do I use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three bonus items in each level - the Bag, Parasol and Hat - allow you to access bonus stage at the end of the level, if you've collected all of them in a single level.

There are two different bonus stages, and you get either depending whether the level timer at the end is even or odd.